# Add all directory contents to jar

Tags: java, windows, jar

I can't force `jar` to package directory *contents* (recursively) to a `.jar` file. It's little bit awkward as it sounds like a basic thing but at least I have now one more argument on why I dislike java.

I have a `bin` directory in my project folder. That directory contains `.class` files in various folders:

[image: image description]

I want to create a jar file that has those files and directories in the root. The structure shall remain the same. I can do this with `7z` Seven zip command:

```
cd bin
7za a -r sample3.jar *.*
```

But Java won't like that a bit. I am really surprised that function such as adding all directory contents is so well hidden.

This is what I tried:

- `jar cf sample3.jar bin/*` or `jar cf sample3.jar bin` creates jar that contains the `bin` directory in root, not the **contained** directories
- This creates jar file that only contains `META-INF`:

  ```
  cd bin
  jar cf sample3.jar *.*
  ```
- Same problem:

  ```
  cd bin
  jar cf sample3.jar *.class
  ```

Is there a simple way to add all directories contents to JAR? This is what I want:

[image: image description]

Comment: First hint: `*.*`, `bin/*` etc contain metacharacters. What do you think interprets them?

Comment: try `jar cf sample3.jar *.class`

Comment: @fge `jar` should interpret them, like 7z does. And if not, then maybe this question is about how to get them interpreted, isn't it?

Comment: If any file is a directory then it is processed recursively.

Comment: So just put `jar cf sample3.jar bin`

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Then why is nothing added to my jar file? You claim it works recursively, but if it does what am I doing wrong? Also your hint does add `bin` directory, not it's contents.

Comment: Well, you got this wrong. 7z will never do that. It is always _the shell interpreter_ which interprets that. It just happens that `*.*` does not find anything in your current directory, and as such is left intact to 7z _which will then_ interpret that. Try and create a directory named `a.b`, run the same command and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, if you are running from `bin` directory

`jar -cfv samples.jar . *.class`

> c - Creates a new archive file named jarfile (if f is specified) or to standard output (if f and jarfile are omitted.
>
> f - Specifies the file jarfile to be created (c), updated (u), extracted (x), indexed (i), or viewed (t). The -f option and filename jarfile are a pair -- if present, they must both appear.
>
> v- Generates verbose output to standard output.
>
> inputfiles (. /*.class) - Files or directories separated by spaces, to be combined into jarfile (for c and u), or to be extracted (for x) or listed (for t) from jarfile. All directories are processed recursively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this did what I needed. Could you explain why `.` and then `*.class` is used?

Answer (score 4):

Try the -C option with 'bin/ .'.  It will "change to the specified directory and include the following file"

```
jar -cvf sample3.jar -C bin/ .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jar uvf sample.jar bin
```

it works for me  ....